# how can I post on facebook and tag a friend and place?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I was reading the new api (opengraph) of Facebook have changed, I am trying to post something and tag couple of friends on it... according this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts I should specify the ids on the part of "tags" but just doesnt work, Ive seen some references but are old...

The problem is that it does post in the wall, but without tagging or showing the place.

I am using php for this.

Anyone have done this??

this is my code

```
$post = array('message' => 'my message ',
                'name' => 'name',
                'caption' => "something", 
                'link' => 'my page',
                'description' =>"some desc",
        'place' => '323816477724410',<--- id of a city
                'tags' => 'xxxxxx', <---- facebook id

                );    
$result = $facebook->api("/".$user."/feed/", 'post', $post);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, check the error log. Put your code inside try{} catch{}, and print the exception array, like this:

```
try{
    $result = $facebook->api("/".$user."/feed/", 'post', $post);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e); // or error_log($e);
}
```